# How to create an array of checkboxes using React Mozilla forms?

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to make a form using https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form

similar to this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/het18xo0/), but here I am trying to make an array of states.

I failed badly at creating jsonschema for the same.

My sample json schema for the same is

```
const schema = {
    type:'object',
  properties:{
    'states':{
          'type':'array',
         items: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          description: {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
const schema = {
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "states":{
            "type":'array',
            "items": {
             "type": "number",
             "enum": [1,2,3],
             "enumNames":["New York","California","Dallas"]
            }
        },
        "uniqueItems": true
    }
}

const uiSchema = {
    "states": {
        "ui:widget": "checkboxes"
    }
}
```

This will render a list of checkboxes, if `uniqueItems` is there.

Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/r7otypfp/
Link to [docs](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form#custom-labels-for-enum-fields)

Hope that helps.

Comment: what if I need one checkbox which shows "select all" and on check need to true all the enums element.